# Can't display image on ImageView

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to diplay an image (selected from gallery) in a fragment. But when I return the onActivityResult is called but the fragment is blank, both methods (loadImageFromGallery and startActivityFromResult are in MainActivity, which host the fragment)

The MainActivity. java

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment;
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_agregarComida) {
            setTitle(R.string.TitleAddFood);
            fragment = new AddFood();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(AddFood.ARG_ADD_FOOD, 0);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        }
}
```

The onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imageViewProfile.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.NoPickPhoto) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.PickPhotoException) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The loadImageGallery

```
public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}
```

My class AddFood which extends Fragment

```
public class AddFood extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_ADD_FOOD = "arg_add_food";
public RatingBar ratingBar;
public EditText NombreComidaEditText;

public AddFood() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_food, container, false);
    //findViewById
    ratingBar = (RatingBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    NombreComidaEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.NombreComidaEditText);
    ratingBar.setNumStars(5);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onCreateViewAddFood",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return rootView;
  }
}
```

And the xml for the ImageView

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/photoTextView"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"/>
```

Here's the result
[image: My fragment]
[image: After Pick image]

Comment: Why do you need the activity to do the work for you? Move that task to the Fragment itself and let it handle its duties

Comment: 'imageViewProfile.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));'. Split that statement as .decodeFile might return a null. And now you never know.